# Extension of Coefficient to variable exponents

Tags: polynomials, variable, coefficients

Say I have an expression that is a polynomial in a variable, for example in the variable $x$, in which terms appear for which the exponent of $x$ also includes variables. For example:

```
pol = a + b x^n + c x^(n + 1)
```

Is there a clean way to find the coefficient in front of any given term?

I could not get the built-in function Coefficient to work directly, namely

```
{Coefficient[pol, x, 0], Coefficient[pol, x, n], Coefficient[pol, x, n + 1]}
```

yields the output

```
{a, b + c x, c}
```

while I want it to yield

```
{a, b, c}
```

To fix this I used

```
Coefficient2[pol_, var_, exp_] := Coefficient[Coefficient[pol, var, exp], var, 0]
```

This was good enough to yield the correct results in my case, but it feels a bit nasty. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to treat `n` and `n+1` differently, why not redefine them like `n0=n`,`n1=n+1`,.. Or put them in an array?

Comment: The problem is that Mathematica does not know that `n` is an integer and therefore the `Coefficient` functions fail. I actually think that your "nasty" hack is pretty slick!

Comment: @Sumit Arrays do not seem to be the right data type for what I am after. Say I have pol1 = a + b x^n + c x^(2n) and pol2 = d + e x^n + f x^(2n) and I want to calculate the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the product pol1 * pol2. If pol1 and pol2 were stored as arrays I would have to write something that multiplies arrays like they are polynomials right? But I do not want to do that since Mathematica already knows how to multiply polynomials. 

Natas, thanks. Maybe it is not too bad. I just thought that there might be a way to do this that feels more mathematically sound.

Comment: Just differentiate with respect to `x` `n` times and evaluate at `x = 0`! :P (Just kidding, but I guess it is how you'd do it "mathematically".)

Comment: In more seriousness, note that `Coefficient` can also be called with arguments as `Coefficient[a + b x^n + c x^(n+1), x^n]`. This seems to work as long as your polynomial is fully expanded! Edit: It also seems to work even if it's *not* fully expanded!

Comment: `List @@ pol /. x -> 1`

Comment: @thorimur, That command still spits out "b + c x" for me, does it yield "b" for you?

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, this is nice but then I still have to figure out which of the entries in the resulting list is actually the coefficient of x^n. Furthermore, it does not work so well when the polynomial is more complicated. Like: pol = a + b x^n + c x^(n + 1) + 10 x^n + y^3*x^(n + 1)

Comment: that's weird...I could've sworn it was working before, but, yeah, no, it gives `b + c x` for me. I guess I must've thought I tested it but not actually tested it exactly as written...so, whoops, sorry about that!

Comment: Interestingly enough, it has no trouble picking out `b` if you ask for `Coefficient[a + b x^n + c x^(2 n), x^n]`. I think the key is the Possible Issues section of the documentation, which says "Coefficient treats transcendental powers as being algebraically unrelated to algebraic powers:" and shows that `Coefficient[x^s x, x^s]` yields `x`. You'd think `Coefficient` would have an option to circumvent this...though, I think that because of this, and because `Coefficient[pol,x,0]` *does* consider `x^n` to be proportional to `x`, your hack is actually reliable.

Comment: Another—though, honestly, probably slower—way to do it, which I've checked works, would be to ask for `Coefficient[pol * x^(-n),x,0]`, taking advantage of this weirdly asymmetrical behavior and the fact that Mathematica doesn't care whether the variable exponents are positive integers or not.

Really, though, what mathematica should do is provide a choice function that depends on `n`. After all, if `n` is `0`, the constant term is `a+b`, not `a`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility for any polynomial `pol` with variable `x` for power `m`

```
powcoeff[pol_, x_, m_] := Simplify[Total[
        Select[Level[Expand[pol], 1], Exponent[#, x] == m &]]/x^m]

pol1 = a1 + b1 x^n + c1 x^(n + 1);
pol2 = a2 + b2 x^n (f x + 1) + c2 x^(n + 1);
pol3 = pol1 pol2;

powcoeff[pol1, x, n]
powcoeff[pol2, x, n + 1]
powcoeff[pol3, x, n]
powcoeff[pol3, x, n + 1]
powcoeff[pol3, x, 6 n + 1]
```

> b1

> c2 + b2 f

> a2 b1 + a1 b2

> a2 c1 + a1 (c2 + b2 f)

> 0